# Custom Rails URL argument separators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, arguments, parameters

We're building a Facebook application at work using Ruby on Rails. We're currently switching it from a canvas to an iframe application for technical reasons.

There is however a problem, Facebook sends you the `fb_sig_api_key` and others as GET varialbes in the URL (`blah.com/?fb_sig_api_key=12345&whatever=hello`).

However, for some reason, Facebook passes the URL with `&amp;` between each variable instead of plain `&`. This causes rails to not get a `fb_sig_api_key` param, but `amp;fb_sig_api_key`.

So, is there any setting in Rails which will make it use `&amp;` and `&` as GET URL argument separators?

If it was PHP it'd be a quick php.ini change, but we're not, so..... help? lol

(At the moment we're working on a quick and ugly before_filter to remote `amp;` from the beginning of all params.)

P.S. We're using Facebooker.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest create another hash in the controller in `before_filter` too

```
before_filter :fetch_params_values

private

def fetch_params_values
  # create another hash to handle querystring
  @params = request.query_string.split(/&amp;/)
end
```